# How to find more words in a file at once?

Tags: python, file, if-statement, printing, find

In my program I am reading another python program and I want to find some special python keywords. When I find them I want to print out some code in front of that keyword found and after it.

This is my code:

```
if line.find("def") == True or line.find("if") == True or line.find("elif") == True:
   print("<span style=\"color: orange;\">",True,"</span>","<br>", end="")
```

In the print statement "True" I want it to be the value that was read by the program.

I don't know if I am doing the "or" statement right but the output is not working.
I don't get any error or anything . I expect my output to be the HTML code above and then the keyword found and the closing HTML code.

Example Output:

```
<span style=\"color: orange;\">if</span>
<span style=\"color: orange;\">def</span> 
<span style=\"color: orange;\">elif</span>
```

Comment: Give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question.

Comment: Got it! I hope this makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by looking up `str.find` in the docs, or just using the built-in help, it doesn't return true or false, it returns the index the substring was found at, or -1 if not found.

So, `line.find("def") == True` will always be false. Whether it was found at column 10 or column 70 or not at all, none of 10, 70, or -1 are equal to True. What you want is `line.find("def") != -1`.

However. there's an even better way: if you don't care about the index, just check `"def" in line`:

```
if "def" in line or "if" in line or "elif" in line:
```

Or, maybe even better:

```
if any(keyword in line for keyword in "def", "if", "elif"):
```

---

By the way, even for functions that *do* return `True` or `False`, you almost never want to check `if x == True`. Basically only when there's multiple possible truthy values, and you need to distinguish `True` from the other ones. Otherwise, just check `if x`.

---

But you're still not going to get the output you want from the `print` you wrote:

```
print("<span style=\"color: orange;\">",True,"</span>","<br>", end="")
```

You're printing the constant `True`; there's no way that could ever print some other string like `def`, it's always just going to print `True`.

If you need to know which one matched, you can't just throw all the conditions together, you have to test each one separately, as the other answers show.

Or… what you're doing here is building a very simple parser. You might want to consider learning how to use PEG or pyparsing or something that will make this easier and less tedious. Or, if the text file really is (legal) Python source code, the Python source code parser that comes built in with the Python stdlib (the `ast` module). Or, for something this simple, just regular expressions:

```
m = re.search(r'def|if|elif', line)
if m:
    print("<span style=\"color: orange;\">", m.group(), "</span>","<br>", end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using `or` in this case and rather breaking this up into `if` and `elif` statements to preserve what keyword was found. Store that in a variable (in this case `value`) and use that in the print statement.

```
if line.find("def") != -1:
    value = "def"
elif line.find("if") != -1:
    value = "if"
elif line.find("elif") != -1:
    value = "elif"
print("<span style=\"color: orange;\">", value,"</span>","<br>", end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
checklist = ['def', 'if', 'elif']
for x in checklist:
    if x in line:
        print("<span style=\"color: orange;\">",x,"</span>","<br>")
```

EDIT:

try this for the case you described below

```
import re
re.compile(r'(((if|elif|else|in)\s*?)+)', re.I).sub(r'<span style=\"color: orange;\">\1</span><br>', line)
```

ONE MORE EDIT:

Try this then:

```
checklist = ['def', 'if', 'elif']
array = line.split(' ')
output = []
for x in array:
    if x in checklist:
        output.append("<span style=\"color: orange;\">%s</span><br>" % x)
    else:
        output.append(x)
print(' '.join(output))
```

Comment: I like this one and is kinda working but for example the keyword "in" when used like above if x "in" line. That is also an orange word. How can I print out the line until the "in" word and then the rest of the line? For example: print(line[:x]"<span style=\"color: orange;\">",x,"</span>",line[x:]"<br>", end="")

Comment: you can print it.. I'm not too familiar with what your use case is, but this will wrap the tags around any of the words in that list but print out the whole line

Comment: ok so it did print it but now every time the line has the word "if" in it even if the word if is in the keyword "elif" this is going to duplicate the line with an if line than with an elif line and then the original line.

Comment: my code now looks like this: for line in infile: for x in checklist: if x in line: maybe because of the 2 for loops is why it duplicates?

Comment: I added one more try. Please let me know how it works

Comment: Well I deleted the print you put in else because it gave me like 100 lines and it duplicated a lot of things but after I deleted the print you put in else and I didn't get the orange keywords...